# prove the following linear functional is not induced by measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory

Let the linear functional $I$ below defined on $C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$. as follows:

$$I(f) = \frac{df}{dx}(0)$$

Prove it's not induced by a measure,or even signed measure.that is no such measure makes $I(f) = \int fd\mu = \frac{df}{dx}(0)$.

I try to use sequence of function $f_n$ such that makes $\frac{df_n}{dx}(0) \to \infty$,but the total mass of $\int f_nd\mu \to 0$ ?If exist such measure it can not be the Lebesgue measure ,since we can construct such function,can it holds for some other measures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an argument that works for signed measures.  Suppose by contradiction that $\mu$ exists and let us analyse $\mu$ on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$.

If $f$ is any function in $C_c^1(\mathbb R\setminus \{0\})$ then we may extend $f$ to the whole real line by setting $f(0)=0$, and it will follow that $f'(0)=0$, so
$$\int f d\mu=0.$$  This implies that the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$ vanishes so $\mu$ must be a multiple of the Dirac measure at $0$, but this clearly doesn't work either, hence $\mu$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Ruy,can you elaborate more on the  why  $\int f d\mu=0.$ implies $\mu$ vanish over $\Bbb{R}\\{0\}$?

Comment: This is because for every compact subset $E$ of $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$, one may write the characteristic function of $E$ as the pointwise limit of a decreasing sequence in $C_c^1(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})$.

Comment: Hi Ruy,the decreasing sequence converge to the charateristic function is due to DCT correct?  If we have proved it  vanish on all compact set,due to regularility of measure,then it will holds for all measurable set on it ,But regularility is the property of Radon measure?

Comment: Yes, I guess this argument assumes regularity of the measure.  Without regularity it is very difficult to say anything about a measure when the assumptions only refer to continuous functions.

Comment: I found a point makes it work,note that for $\Bbb{R}$ 
(Borel) measure finite on compact set implies regularility,since topology is LCH and second countble,the measure is finite on all compact set since functional is defined for all function $f\in C^1_c(\Bbb{R})$

Comment: Excellent point!  This is spelled out in full in Theorem 21.20 in Royden & Fitzpatrick's book "Real Analysis".

Answer (score 3):

Assume that there is some (positive) measure $\mu$ that induces this functional. Clearly $\mu\ne0$.

Take $f_n(x)$ a function such that

- $f_n(x)=1$ if $x\in[-n,n]$.
- $f_n(x)=0$ if $x\notin [-n-1,n+1]$.
- $f_n\in{\cal C}^1(\Bbb R)$.
- $0\le f_n(x)\le 1$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$.

Then $I(f_n)=f_n'(0)=0$, obviously.

On the other hand,
$I(f_n)=\int_{\Bbb R} f_nd\mu \ge \int_{(-n,n)} f_n d\mu=\int_{(-n,n)}d\mu=\mu(-n,n)
$.

So $\mu(-n,n)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$; and since $\Bbb R=\bigcup_n (-n,n)$, by subaditivity, $\mu(\Bbb R)\le \sum_n \mu(-n,n)=0$, so $\mu=0$, wich is a contradiction.

Comment: If we assume $I$ is represented by a measure, it is safer to assume that the measure is signed. This is because there are smooth compactly  supported nonnegative functions with strictly negative derivative at zero.

Comment: And? Whats the problem? If $\mu$ is a positive measure, then $\int (-\chi_A)d\mu=-\mu(A)$ (and you can approximate $-\chi_A$ by smooth functions maintaining negativity.

Comment: 1) It is reasonable to assume the measure is signed. Otherwise the argument is immediate: take ANY nonnegative compactly supported function with strictly negative derivative at zero and you have a contradiction; 2) The argument presented above fails if $\mu$ is a signed measure because it relies on the assumption $f\ge 0 \Rightarrow \int f d\mu \ge 0$, which is no longer valid for signed measures.

Comment: For the sake of clearity, I edit my answer to specify positivity of $\mu$. So the answer is valid for positive measuires.

Answer (score 2):

Take $f \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ with $f \geq 0$ but $f'(0)<0.$ Then $I(f)<0$ but $\int f\,d\mu \geq 0.$ Contradiction!

Such an $f$ can be constructed by smoothing
$$
f_0(x) = \begin{cases}
2-x & \text{when $-1<x<1$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
for example by convolution with a narrow enough [nascent delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#nascent_delta_function).